# Win10 UWP C#: Access variables form another class/view

Tags: c#, .net, windows, win-universal-app

I'm currently reading into Serial Communication in Win10. I'm using this approach:

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm

However, I want now access to the SerialInput stream from another view. (Other than the MainPage).

```
public byte[] rxbytes = new byte[06];
...
        private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

    uint ReadBufferLength = 24;

    // If task cancellation was requested, comply
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
    dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

    // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream
    loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);

    // Launch the task and wait
    UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
    rxbytes= new byte[bytesRead];
    dataReaderObject.ReadBytes(rxbytes);


}
```

Basically this works perfect if I want to write all the code into one view. But I need to get access to the "rxbytes"-array in order to process the incoming data.

One option would be:

```
this.AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(page2), rxbytes);
```

This is approach is giving me the six empty bytes on the 2nd page. A getter and setter method is also not an option as the variable is not static.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

there are some options.

You can save all data in the storage of  your app after that you just need to get all the saved data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx

Another way is creating a static class where you can save in a property the data and get the data in the second view.